# Determine which WTForms button was pressed in a Flask view

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a page with multiple links to redirect the user to different pages.  I thought using a form would be nicer, so I defined a WTForms `Form` with multiple `SubmitFields`.  How do I determine which button was clicked and redirect based on that?

```
class MainForm(Form):
    user_stats = SubmitField('User Stats')
    room_stats = SubmitField('Room Stats')

@main.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    form = MainForm()    
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You added two buttons to the form, so check which of the fields' data is `True`.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'davidism'

class StatsForm(Form):
    user_stats = SubmitField()
    room_stats = SubmitField()

@app.route('/stats', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stats():
    form = StatsForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.user_stats.data:
            return redirect(url_for('user_stats'))
        elif form.room_stats.data:
            return redirect(url_for('room_stats'))

    return render_template('stats.html', form=form)

app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<form method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.user_stats }}
    {{ form.room_stats }}
</form>
```