# How to use onclick function for SubmitField in Flask (WTF SubmitField problem)

Tags: python, flask, onclick, pymongo

how can use on-click function for flask `SubmitField` input option?

i want call function using `SubmitField` in flask form, because i want to use multiple button in one form, so i need specific function for one button.

```py
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',validators=[DataRequired(), Length( min=1, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password',validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    signUpbtn = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

```py
def register():
    signUpform = RegistrationForm()
    if signUpform.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {signUpform.username.data}!', 'success')
        db_cm.insert({'username':signUpform.username.data, 'email':signUpform.email.data, 'password':signUpform.password.data})
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    #else:
    #    flash('Please check input data!', 'danger ')
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=signUpform)
```

i need add another button how can manage that?

Comment: i got the answer form here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774060/determine-which-wtforms-button-was-pressed-in-a-flask-view

Answer (score 9):

If I understand the question correctly you want to render a button that looks like this...

```
<input id="signUpbtn" name="signUpbtn" type="submit" onclick="your_submit_function()" value="Sign Up">
```

You can simply use the `render_kw` argument. It accepts a dictionary of name value pairs that it renders as HTML attributes.

Your code would look something like this...

```
signUpbtn = SubmitField('Sign Up', render_kw={"onclick": "your_submit_function()"})
```

Comment: yes, you got my question. but that's not work for me. i can't call my function yet